# Build AWS IAM policy from JSON array of account numbers

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I have a list of AWS account numbers that I want to dynamically use to build an AWS policy. Here is my example:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "splunk-config-bucket" {
  bucket        = "${var.config_bucket_name}"
  force_destroy = true
  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = "${data.aws_kms_alias.kms_name.arn}"
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
  tags = {
    Product = "Splunk - AWS Config Logs"
    Service = "Security"
  }

 lifecycle_rule {
    id      = "log"
    enabled = true

    prefix = "*"

    transition {
      days          = 7
      storage_class = "GLACIER"
    }

    expiration {
      days = 14
    }
  }

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSConfigAclCheck20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "config.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSConfigWrite20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "config.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/123456789/*”,
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/123456789/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/123456789/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/123456789/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/123456789/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/123456789/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/123456789/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/123456789/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/123456789/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/123456789/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "configlogs_bucketnotification" {
  bucket = "${var.config_bucket_name}"

  queue {
    queue_arn     = "${aws_sqs_queue.splunk_configlogs_sqs_queue.arn}"
    events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
  }
}
```

I have a list of account numbers in an envs.json file, it looks like this:

```
{
    "accounts": [
        "1234567890",
        "0987654321",
        "1029384756",
        "6574839201",
        "0192837465"
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to generate the policy with a dynamic list of AWS account numbers. We're trying to get away from hard-coding account numbers and pulling this from a "centralised config" project we have.

Here is what I've tried:

variables.tf:

```
locals {
    accounts = jsondecode(file("../configuration/envs.json")).accounts
}
```

Config.tf

```
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "config.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": ${jsonencode(formatlist("arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/%s/*", local.accounts))}
            "Condition": {
```

This gives me the following output when I run "terraform plan":

```
Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character '"' after object key:value pair

  on central_config.tf line 2, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "splunk-config-bucket":
   2: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "splunk-config-bucket" {
```

I've also tried this:

variables.tf

```
locals {
  accounts = jsondecode(file("../configuration/envs.json")).accounts
}

output "example" {
  value = jsonencode(formatlist("arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWS/AWSLogs/%s/*", local.accounts))
}
```

config.tf

```
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "config.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": ${local.accounts.output.value}
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
```

This is the output I get:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on central_config.tf line 60, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "splunk-config-bucket":
  60:             "Resource": ${local.accounts.output.value}
    |----------------
    | local.accounts is tuple with 35 elements

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you looking for something like what is described here?  I don't use AWS so I need a little more to go on. https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/aws/iam-policy

Comment: Hey- Thanks for getting involved, I've added more details. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can load the file using the [`file` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/file.html) and then extract the list of accounts that you'll need by decoding the JSON with [`jsondecode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsondecode.html) and then selecting the `accounts` key.

As an example:

```
locals {
  accounts = jsondecode(file("accounts.json")).accounts
}

output example {
  value = local.accounts
}
```

This will return the following:

```
example = [
  "1234567890",
  "0987654321",
  "1029384756",
  "6574839201",
  "0192837465",
]
```

If you then wanted to put that into your policy you'd want to use the [`formatlist` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/formatlist.html) to pass a list of accounts into a single string format:

```
output "example" {
  value = formatlist("arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/%s/*", local.accounts)
}
```

This outputs:

```
example = [
  "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/1234567890/*",
  "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/0987654321/*",
  "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/1029384756/*",
  "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/6574839201/*",
  "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/0192837465/*",
]
```

If you notice carefully though, Terraform uses trailing commas in lists which is invalid JSON so would create an invalid JSON structure for your IAM policy. To fix that we can then re-encode it into JSON with [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html):

```
output "example" {
  value = jsonencode(formatlist("arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/%s/*", local.accounts))
}
```

Which then outputs:

```
example = ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/1234567890/*","arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/0987654321/*","arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/1029384756/*","arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/6574839201/*","arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/0192837465/*"]
```

without the trailing comma.

Putting this altogether you can then create your IAM policy like this:

```
locals {
  accounts = jsondecode(file("accounts.json")).accounts
}

resource aws_iam_policy policy {
  name        = "example"
  path        = "/"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ${jsonencode(formatlist("arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/AWSLogs/%s/*", local.accounts))}
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you for putting the time in to reply to this one. The only issue I seem to be having is trying to get the output as input back into my policy on another "file.tf" when it runs through. I may be missing the point. Is this possible or should I be tackling it from a different angle?

Comment: I'm running into this problem: Error: Unsupported attribute

  on central_config.tf line 61, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "splunk-config-bucket":
  61:                 "${local.accounts.formatted_list}"
    |----------------
    | local.accounts is tuple with 35 elements

This value does not have any attributes.

Comment: Sorry, the output was more for demonstration. I've added a more fully worked example that creates an IAM policy.

Comment: Does the more fully worked example help here? It's hard to tell what issues you're having without seeing a [mcve] of your issue. The fully worked example definitely will do what you need but you might be running into another issue here so it might be worth editing your question to include that if relevant or even opening another question if you're stuck on another thing that's not related to this specific question.

Comment: Gotcha - I was on the right lines. Feels like I'm so close! I'm now getting the following: "Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character '"' after object key:value pair"

Comment: That sounds like you're doing something different to what is in my answer or you have your account list in a different format. It would be helpful to edit your question into a [mcve] that fully shows just the creation of the IAM policy (before my answer influenced anything) and potentially also include a separate step afterwards with what you have now after my answer.

Comment: I've added more context into the above- Hopefully I've explained it enough *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this working with help from ydaetskcoR:

Here is my variables file:

```
locals {
  accounts = jsondecode(file("../configuration/envs.json")).accounts
  config = jsonencode(formatlist("arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/%s/*", local.accounts))
}
```

I could test the output by using Terraform console:

```
> jsonencode(formatlist("arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/%s/*", local.accounts))
["arn:aws:s3:::bby-central-configlogs-splunk/AWSLogs/123456789/*","arn:aws:s3:::bby-central-configlogs-splunk/AWSLogs/123456789/*"]
```

As you can see it has [] around them:
I put the following into my policy:

```
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "config.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": ${local.config},
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
```

I thought I would put my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Getting JSON encoding right with string templates can be frustrating. Unless there's a strong reason to format the JSON a particular way, we can avoid templating JSON by constructing the desired data structure directly and then passing it to `jsonencode`, like this:

```
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid    = "AWSConfigAclCheck20150319"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "config.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Action   = "s3:GetBucketAcl"
        Resource = "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}"
      },
      # etc, etc
    ]
  })
```

You can then use Terraform's operators and functions directly to construct parts of that object. For example, to produce the list of ARNs you wanted:

```
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      # ...
      {
        Sid    = "AWSConfigWrite20150319"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "config.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Action   = "s3:PutObject"
        Resource = [for acct in local.accounts : "arn:aws:s3:::${var.config_bucket_name}/AWSLogs/${acct}/*"]
      },
      # ...
    ]
  })
```

If the policy becomes complicated enough that you want to factor it out into a separate template file, you can still use the `jsonencode` function by making the entire template be a `jsonencode` call:

```
${jsonencode({
  # ...
})}
```

Using `jsonencode` for the whole structure at once means the result is guaranteed to be valid JSON, without needing to worry about exactly where to place commas and other delimiters as you would need to when constructing JSON as a template.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a dynamic config reload in your code that updates the list of accounts and calls S3 API when the config file changes.

For the purpose of watching on config file (account list) you can use some libraries. I believe "Viper" is a good choice.

And also if you are worried about losing these kind of events on file caused by API call failures or application crash, you can try to make updating the action list idempotent and do it on application start or in an interval.

These links might come in hand:

About idempotency: https://nordicapis.com/understanding-idempotency-and-safety-in-api-design/

Viper: https://github.com/spf13/viper

Comment: Thank you for this - I'll look into it and try and get it working :)